# Wrong string formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, string-formatting

Here's the program:

```
layout = "{0:>5}"
layout += "{1:>10}"
for i in range(2, 13):
    layout += "{"+str(i)+":9>}"


index = []
for i in range(13):
    index.append(i)
index = tuple(index)
print(layout.format(*index))
```

and it prints out like this:

```
    0         123456789101112
```

but I want it to look something like this(number of spaces might be wrong):

```
    0    1   2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
":9>}"
```

should be

```
":>9}"
```

This gives:

```
    0         1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12
```

---

<s>To look exactly like what you ask:</s>

Actually, you're asking for something weird, but here's a more succint way to write what you wrote:

```
layout = "{0:>5}{1:>5}" + ''.join("{" + str(i) + ":>4}" for i in range(2, 13))
print(layout.format(*range(13)))
```

Gives:

```
    0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```